# When I make a paypal payment, it does not move to the database. Can this be corrected?

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal

When I try to pay with PayPal an error occurs and the button does not work, this is the JavaScript code:

```
 $('.paypal-button-row').on('click', function(event) {
     var account_id = $('#account_id').text();
     var email = $('input[name="email"]').val();
     var sesid = $('input[name="sesid"]').val();
     $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php?func=create_order',
        data: {
            'account_id': account_id,
            'email': email,
            'sesid': sesid
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response == "success") {
                console.log(success);
                $(this).off("submit").trigger("submit");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this is the button:

```
 <div id="smart-button-container">
     <div style="text-align: center;">
         <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This is php code of button:

```
public function create_order() {
    $sesid = $_POST["sesid"];
    $account_id=(int) $_POST["account_id"];
    print_r($account_id);
    $user_id =(string) $_COOKIE['user_id'];
    echo $user_id;
    $accountsell = $this->query_executor("SELECT * FROM accountsell WHERE status=? AND account_id=?","ii",array(1,$account_id))->fetch_assoc();

    $accountsell_id = (int) $accountsell["id"];
    echo '-'.$accountsell_id;
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    echo "<br>".$email;
    $this->query_executor("INSERT INTO ordered_accounts VALUES(NULL,?,?,?,?,?,0,NOW())","siiss",array($sesid,$accountsell_id,$account_id,$user_id,$email));
    var_dump(array($sesid,$accountsell_id,$account_id,$user_id,$email));

    $_SESSION["sesid"] = $sesid;
    echo "success";
    
}
```

[This is photo of PayPal pay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUUo3.png)

It is gaming site, Can this be corrected?

Comment: `an error occurs` which one exactly...? (also, did you set up the payment correctly in your paypal account? Incuding your PHP script's public URL? when you add logging to your PHP script, i.e. saving  info to a text file, does that every happen? etc.)

Comment: No information is transferred to the database

Comment: It seems that your codes (ajax) are triggered when the element with class paypal-button-row is triggered ? (but where is your "paypal-button-row" in your codes ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.paypal-button-row').on('click'...
```

Nothing about this makes any sense (it's completely wrong to be adding your own click handler to the row), so see a correct sample here instead: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

If you need to pass additional parameters in your create call, add a body object to the fetch.

You'll need two corresponding routes on your server that return their own JSON, one for that first 'Create an order' and one for the 'Capture order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).

When the capture order is successful, immediately write whatever you need into your database before returning the JSON.